# Binary search optimisation

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search

I implemented binary search in two ways and wondering which is more efficient? please help me know which is more efficient and how can it further be optimized? is time complexity remains same in both approach? I am a beginner in programming.

approach 1;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool BinarySearch(int*a,int n,int s ){
    if(n==1){
        if(a[0]==s)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else{
        if(s<a[n/2]){
            int U[n/2];
            for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++){
                U[i]=a[i];
            }
            return BinarySearch(U,n/2,s);
        }
        else{
            int V[n-n/2];
            for(int i=0;i<n-n/2;i++){
                V[i]=a[i+n/2];
            }
            return BinarySearch(V,n-n/2,s);
        }

    }
}
int main(){
int array[10]={2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,22};
cout<<BinarySearch(array,10,9);
}
```

approach 2:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    bool Bsearch(int arr[],int s,int l,int x){
        cout<<"calling bsearch with arguments "<<s<<' '<<l<<' '<<x<<endl;
        if(l==1)
            return arr[s]==x;
        int h=l/2;
        if(x<arr[s+h])
            return Bsearch(arr,s,h,x);
        else
            return Bsearch(arr,s+h,l-h,x);
    }
int main(){
    int marks[11]={17,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36};
    cout<<Bsearch(marks,0,11,32);
}
```

Thanks in advance for the kind help.

Comment: `int U[n/2];` -- VLAs are not valid C++, only supported as non-standard extension on some compilers. Copying is less efficient anyway. The second one is the way to go.

Comment: Variable-length arrays are non-standard, and error-prone (try to search in a larger array - say, a few million elements), but copying is almost always less efficient than not copying.

Comment: Also, clang, g++, and VC++ all optimize the recursion in the second into loops, but that's impossible in the first.

Comment: @molbdnilo sir I see my code show red tilde for U[n/2] but it compiles perfectly in vs code, I think array will always be of variable length for this operation and we always initialized n.

Comment: @Rajakr Again, such arrays are not part of standard C++. You're using a non-portable compiler extension, and even if you stick to this compiler, your program will crash eventually.

Comment: ohhkay got it sir,In merge sort i used to divide array by this way only,yeah second one seems less error prone as well

Comment: @molbdnilo sir and dratenik sir, i would like to understand will both approach have same time complexity of O(log n)?

Comment: They will not, because of your unnecessary copying (which also destroys the nice constant space complexity).

Answer (score 1):

Other posters are correct that variable-length arrays are not good C++. If you define your `main()` as:

```
int main() {
    std::array<int> marks{17,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36};
    cout<<Bsearch(marks,0,32);
}
```

or:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> marks{17,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36};
    cout<<Bsearch(marks,0,32);
}
```

then you can drop the pointer/length pair in the parameter list to your binary-search function. The function prototype becomes something like:

```
bool Bsearch(const std::array<int>& arr, int s, int x);
```